# Can Google Visualization: Pie Chart output to a PNG image?

Tags: google-visualization

Google Visualization API can draw the pie chart in the website with javascript.
Can the chart be output as a PNG image file?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, only the old-style Image Chart is **not** suitable for my need.

Comment: This tutorial show how transform the charts generated by google charts in a image, i hope it helps: http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use the static image [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/)

At least, you can until [20 Apr 2015](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) :(

Comment: Thanks. I found the image pie chart which is suitable in my case.

Comment: The new JSAPI is very attractive but the HTML codes are in <g> tags. Is there any way we can convert that cool output(https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) into image?

Comment: Sorry to say, but the old image API is now deprecated - ttl = 2015: https://developers.google.com/chart/terms

Comment: One quick question: will the whole google chart api be only available until 20 Apr 2015? Or just the static chart generator? -- Never mind, just read it on the site: "Important: The Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy."

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  This is no longer natively supported in the Google Visualization API, but it only requires a few lines of JavaScript, below.

The solution, originally, described by Riccardo Govoni in the wonderful [Battlehorse tutorial](http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html), converts SVG to Canvas and then to PNG, which can then be displayed or saved.

The tutorial code no longer works, but I added two fixes to it:

1. Set the `chartArea` variable to work with Google Visualization API version 1.32 (Sept 24, 2012) and later ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824542/571733))
2. Use canvg.js r157 as a workaround for a [regression](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/issues/detail?id=202) identified by [nverba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902551/nverba)

.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvg.googlecode.com/svn-history/r157/trunk/canvg.js"></script>
<script>
  function getImgData(chartContainer) {
    var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
    var svg = chartArea.innerHTML;
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', chartArea.offsetWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', chartArea.offsetHeight);

    canvas.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'position: absolute; ' +
        'top: ' + (-chartArea.offsetHeight * 2) + 'px;' +
        'left: ' + (-chartArea.offsetWidth * 2) + 'px;');
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
    canvg(canvas, svg);
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
    return imgData;
  }

  function saveAsImg(chartContainer) {
    var imgData = getImgData(chartContainer);

    // Replacing the mime-type will force the browser to trigger a download
    // rather than displaying the image in the browser window.
    window.location = imgData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  }

  function toImg(chartContainer, imgContainer) { 
    var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
    var img = doc.createElement('img');
    img.src = getImgData(chartContainer);

    while (imgContainer.firstChild) {
      imgContainer.removeChild(imgContainer.firstChild);
    }
    imgContainer.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    // Pie chart
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
    data.addRows(5);
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Work');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 11);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Eat');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(2, 0, 'Commute');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(3, 0, 'Watch TV');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 2);
    data.setValue(4, 0, 'Sleep');
    data.setValue(4, 1, 7);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 450, height: 300, title: 'My Daily Activities'});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="google_visualization_div"></div>

<button onclick="saveAsImg(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'));">Save as PNG Image</button>
<button onclick="toImg(document.getElementById('google_visualization_div'), document.getElementById('img_div'));">Convert to image</button>
<hr>
<div id="img_div">
  Image will be placed here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in IE8 im facing trouble in chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode; how can i resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I found this, but have not yet tested it:
https://gist.github.com/battlehorse/1333906

Looks like it uses canvas to clientside convert the data into SVG/PNG, which will print.

Comment: This does not work since the update where they removed iframes over half a year ago. See comments here for solution. http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html