# Saving and printing a google chart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have been trying to save and/or print a google chart but with no luck.  I have tried what has been suggested https://gist.github.com/battlehorse/1333906 and [Can Google Visualization: Pie Chart output to a PNG image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660498/can-google-visualization-pie-chart-output-to-a-png-image/16137983#16137983) but i cant seem to get it working.  I copied and pasted the code into notepad and saved it as .html and then opened with firefox.  When i click the save button, the download box appears but it does not recognise it as a png and will not download anything.

Anyone have any ideas what is wrong with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download was never recognized as a png - you always had to rename it manually.  I tested the [Nverba fork](https://gist.github.com/nverba/5411684) of that code, which updates the code to reflect the improvements in the Visualization API, and it functions in Chrome but not Firefox.  Since the code used to work in Firefox, I assume that either an update to Firefox or the canvg library broke functionality in Firefox (there's nothing specific in the Visualization API that would cause functionality in Firefox to break).  Since this is a highly browser-specific tool anyway, I would just recommend using Chrome to handle your chart-to-image conversion.

Comment: you are correct, I had tried with ie and firefox but not chrome and assumed i had done something wrong. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You can have it printed directly from your browser, or from JavaScript via the `window.print()` function.

References here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing