# Using client-side gauge chart

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to build a client-side gauge chart in CF10. I would like to customize the high and low end of the gauge. But the `scaleTo` value has no effect. The highest number is always the highest data value. Is there a way to customize the highest number on the gauge?

Here is my cf code:

```
<cfchart format="html" scalefrom="0" scaleto="40">
  <cfchartseries type="gauge">
    <cfchartdata item="Series1" value="15">
    <cfchartdata item="Series2" value="10">
  </cfchartseries>
</cfchart>
```

And here is the output shown in the browser.
[image: gauge output]

Comment: Not an answer for your question but if you're in a jam the google gauge charts are very easy and quick to set up. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge

Comment: I currently am using the Google visualizations but would like to replace with the CF code. The Google Visualizations are great tools but the one drawback is the lack of ability to easily copy the chart to the clipboard for pasting into other programs. With CF, I can copy the chart to the clipboard (as a PNG or JPG) and paste it somewhere else. I love the layout and flexibility the Google gauge provides.

Comment: Here's an approach which allows you to turn a google chart into a PNG. not tried it myself, but it may be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16137983/826714